# Where can I find a good example of a Core Data to-many relationship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Does anyone have a tutorial or source code that shows a to-many relationship being used, where the user add elements in on the fly? I would just like to have a look because reading about it hasnt been much help.

Comment: what part of to-many relationships are you struggling with?

Comment: Maybe i should have said ios, but i guess I'm just not knowledged enough to take snippets of code and drop them into my program...yet, my problem specifically is how to add items to the second entity that correspond with specific ones from the first.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

People are often confused by to-many relationships because one entity represents the relationship as a set while the other represents it as a single object. Take the following entities:

```
EntityA{
    name:string
    bees<-->>EntityB.a
}

EntityB{
    name:string
    a<<-->EntityA.bees
}
```

In EntityA, the relationship `bees` is a set because there maybe many EntityB objects in the relationship. So, using Key-Value coding, you would have to access the relationship using a `mutableSetForKey:` expanding everything out to see the detail would like so:

```
NSMutableSet *muteSet=[anEntityAObj mutableSetValueForKey:@"bees"];
[muteSet addObject:aNewBObj];
[anEntityAObj setValueForKey:@"bees"];
```

...or more compactly:

```
[[anEntityAObj mutableSetValueForKey:@"bees"] addObject:aNewBObj];
```

If you set from the EntityB side, however, you are only adding a single object so you can just use setValueForKey: directly like so:

```
[anEntityBObj setValueForKey:anEntityAObj];
```

That's if you use generic NSManagedObject instances to represent your entities. If you create custom subclasses then you have properties and methods to do the setting for you:

```
[anEntityAObj addBeesObject:anEntityBObj];
anEntityBObj.a=anEntityAObj;
```

Remember as well that with managed objects, setting one side of a relationship defined as reciprocal automatically set the other side as well and removing works the same way.

### Update

> Lets say i've got 2 entities --
>   Person:with "name" attribute --
>   Times:with "time" attribute -- i would
>   want to set multiple times for each
>   name, but how to I tell it which name
>   i would like to add the specific times
>   to?

You don't create relationships with attributes, in this case `name` but rather with an object, in this case an instances of the `Person` entity/class.  Each individual `Person` object is completely separate from all other `Person` objects even if they have the same value in their `name` attribute.

You must obtain a reference to any particular `Parent` object. If you have just inserted a new `Parent` object then you already have a reference to it. If it is already been inserted/persisted, then you create a fetch with a predicate that will return the proper object. Once you have the correct `Parent` object you then just add the `Time` objects to the relationship.

So, if your entity looks like this pseudo-code:

```
Parent{
    name:string
    times<-->>Time.parent
}

Time{
    theTime:date
    parent<<-->Parent.times
}
```

... and you are using generic NSManagedObjects to instatiate you entities, you set the relationship between an existing `Parent` object and new `Time` object something like this:

```
NSManagedObject *existingParent= //... results of a fetch
    NSManagedObject *newTime=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Time" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
    [newTime setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"theTime"];
    [newTime setValue:existingParent forKey:@"parent"];
```

Note that if you set the relationship from the `Time` object's side, you can use setValue:ForKey: because from the `Time` object's perspective the relationship is just one object to one object.

It is really quite simple once you start thinking in objects instead of databases. Each object you insert in a context is unique even if it shares attributes with other objects of the same entity/class. That is why you can set a relationship between specific objects without necessarily worrying about the values stored in their attributes.

Comment: Lets say i've got 2 entities -- Person:with "name" attribute -- Times:with "time" attribute -- i would want to set multiple times for each name, but how to I tell it which name i would like to add the specific times to?

Comment: Also could you give an example of what aNewBObj might be?

Comment: What if my fetched object has the same name as another? how can I tell it to fetch only exactly the one that I would want?

Comment: That's part of of data model design. You have to include enough information in the attributes to distinguish one object from another. After all, real-objects, events or conditions have a lot of information that distinguishes them and you need to make sure capture that in your data model.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of a one-to-many relationship, as long as you have set up the relationships so they have an inverse they are quite easy to manage. at the end, Entity1's chilren attribute will contain entity2 and entity3

```
Entity1 *entity1=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity1" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Entity2 *entity2=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity2" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Entity2 *entity3=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity2" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[entity2 setParentEntity:entity1];
[entity3 setParentEntity:entity1];
NSError *error;
[[self managedObjectContext]save:&error];

NSSet *set=[entity1 children];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Get Marcus Zarra's book "Core Data" (you can buy a PDF rather than paper for instant gratification...) It too presents examples in Mac OS X but it goes a lot further than just getting started. You will find out useful things like versioning, transition rules, optimization. This book saved one of my projects from being late & slow!

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using this ebook and its very well written:
It explains and shows how to create datamodels and there are also there are code examples..

"Pro Core Data for iOS"
http://apress.com/book/view/1430233559

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Download the [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913) sample code. It's a full working demo of Core Data and an excellent way to get familiarized with the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to see in the "Learn Cocoa on the Mac" book sources. In the chapters 7 and 8.

- [Here for the book](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430218593)
- [Here for the sources](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4528)

I hope you'll find what you need

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html).

I create objects and add them to relationships using mutableSetValueForKey:

> mutableSetValueForKey: returns a mutable proxy object. If you mutate its contents, it will emit the appropriate key-value observing (KVO) change notifications for the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has great Core Data tutorials.

[this one deals with to-many relationships](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates)

which builds off

[this great 3-part intro to core data tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)