# How to save more than one people in an Entity (CoreData)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an entity which looks like this:

```
Entityname = Country
```

with the attributes "city" and "person".

```
Country *country = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    country.city = @"New York";
    country.person = @"Doug";
    country.person = @"Carry";
    country.person = @"Arthur";
```

I want to save more then one **people** in that **City**.

I am using the code posted above, but only the last person is saved.

How I can save more then one **people** in **CoreData**?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach for solving your problem would be:

1. Create **3 Entities**: **Country**, **City** and **Person**
2. Setup the properties for your entities (e.g. Country.name, City.name, Person.name etc) using the graphical tool of XCode
3. Setup the relations between your Entities. You need a one-to-many from Country -> City [call it cities] and a one-to-many from City -> Person [call it persons] (See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075) regarding this subject). Keep in mind that you will need to set the inverse relations as well.
4. That's where all the fun begins... Choose Editor > Create NSManagedObject subclass. Xcode then will generate the files based on your model. Now if you look at the header files, you should see among the generated methods something similar to this:

...

```
- (void)addPersonObject:(Person *)value;
- (void)removePersonObject:(Person *)value;
- (void)addPersons:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removePersons:(NSSet *)value;
```

...

From this point is quite obvious to figure out how to add multiple objects :)
I know that all this may seem hard at first but once you get yourself into this you will really be able to manage complex object graphs easy and efficiently.
I hope that this information will set you on the right track!

Comment: i tried it but i dont know how to add multable objects with this methods. It is very complicated, maybe you can help me a little how to implement this methods

Comment: You can find a very detailed answer on the subject (one-to-many relationship) by @TechZen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399195/where-can-i-find-a-good-example-of-a-core-data-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an array with all the people you need to save to the core data model.

Comment: How can i do that? I know how to fill a array, but how i save a Array too CoreData?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Hope this will help you

```
yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWIthObjects:@"Doug",@"Carry",@"Arthur"];

for(int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++)
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    countryObject=[NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" 
                              inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
    countryObject.city = @"New york";
    countryObject.people = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**AFTER YOU EXPLAINED THAT YOU DONT NEED THREE DIFFERENT INSTANCES,** then

This can be done by creating a separate entity for `City` and `People`, then make a relationship between them as `to-many relationship.` So that you can achieve like that.

Comment: thx, that helped me alot. But now i have another problem. I fetched this data in a dynamic tableviewcontroller with a custom cell. If i use your Code, he generate 3 cell with City = NewYork and splits the array, for example. Cell 1 = Doug, Cell 2 = Carry... In my case i need that he just create one cell with the name "New York" and this three attributes.

Comment: This can be done by creating a separate entity for City and People, then make a relationship between them as to-many relationship. So that you can achieve like that.

Comment: otherwise iterate your loop and concatenate all three values in that array and store in a single string and then store that string into core data

Comment: This doesn't add three people to a city, it creates three instances of `Country`, each with the same `city` but different `people` values. That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Caleb check out my other comments. Not only that guy and you too cant save three people in a same Country name without making to many relationship or a single string.

Comment: @R.A That's why a to-many relationship, as described by Alladinian, is the right way to go.

Comment: @Caleb check my comment, i posted before 2 mins to "Alladinian" answer is same as my concept. I thought to don't do several answer for same question. So i put that in comment.