# How do I save multiple "instances" of an entity in Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data

TL;DR I am new to Core Data. My understanding of an Entity in Core Data is that it is similar to a class. If so, how do I save multiple "instances" (NSManagedObjects?) of an Entity to Core Data? It seems like every time I save my managed object, I overwrite the one written before it.

I like the properties contained in the entity I created (MathFlashcard). I'd like to save many MathFlashcards to Core Data, each with their own properties. What's the best way to do this?

It seems like a lot of people on StackExchange have had the same question. I was not able to form a satisfactory answer based on these. Reading Apple's documentation has likewise proved fruitless. I haven't formed an answer to this question from reading through Ray Wenderlich and Big Ranch tutorials either.

edit: I tried moving my declaration of each entity into the for loop, but I'm still getting faults and errors. I've pasted my code below! Maybe someone can spot what's wrong.

```
@IBAction func makeCardsAndSave(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Access the managed context
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

        // Create an entity
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MathFact", in: context)!

        //Create FlashCards
        let flashCards: FlashCards = FlashCards(properties: selectedFacts)

        for fact in flashCards.facts {
            if !fact.isEmpty {
                let newFact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MathFact", into: context) as NSManagedObject
                newFact.setValue(fact[0], forKeyPath: "firstInteger")
                newFact.setValue(fact[1], forKeyPath: "secondInteger")
                newFact.setValue(fact[2], forKeyPath: "ans")
                newFact.setValue(fact[3], forKeyPath: "box")
            }

            // Try to save
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

        }

        // Testing the save
        fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "MathFact")

        var testFetch: [NSManagedObject] = []
        do {
            testFetch = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        print(testFetch)
    }
```

Comment: I find this much relatable to your question. So maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841257/11815440
and if you are using many related entities you can also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400158/11815440

Comment: To create a new instance you use an initializer, like with any other class, in [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) which is the super class of your entities. See the topic  “Initializing a Managed Object” in the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to make new instance of each of your objects.

```
import CoreData

let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let entity_ mathFlashcard =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MathFlashcard", in:managedContext)

for _ in 1..<10 {
    let mathFlashcard = MathFlashcard(entity: entity_ mathFlashcard!, insertInto: managedContext)
    mathFlashcard.title = "Title"
    // your other attributes
}

do {
     try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError  {
     print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I think I see what you're getting at. To clarify, your implementation of MathFlashcard in your example code is a subclass of NSManagedObject, correct?

Comment: That is correct, I thought you have it like this right?